# Using Source Generator to create simpler method overload

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, sourcegenerators

I got a class that currently needs to be registered like this (to work reflection-free)

```cs
ViewLocator = new StrongViewLocator()
    .Register<MainWindowViewModel>(new ViewDefinition(typeof(MainWindow), () => new MainWindow()))
    .Register<AddTextDialogViewModel>(new ViewDefinition(typeof(AddTextDialog), () => new AddTextDialog()));
```

I want to get the equivalent of the above code generated using this simpler syntax.

```cs
ViewLocator = new StrongViewLocator()
    .Register<MainWindowViewModel, MainWindow>()
    .Register<AddTextDialogViewModel, AddTextDialog>();
```

How can I achieve this with Source Generator?

Comment: I'm not sure how it is relevant to Source Generators. Source Generator generates new code during the build. Here, it seems that extension method will suffice.

Comment: Why not rather make an extension method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe an extension method will suffice.

Something like this:

```
public static StrongViewLocator Register<TViewModel, TWindow>(this StrongViewLocator viewLocator)
    where TWindow : new()
{
    // .Register<MainWindowViewModel>(new ViewDefinition(typeof(MainWindow), () => new MainWindow()))
    // .Register<MainWindowViewModel, MainWindow>()

    return viewLocator.Register<TViewModel>(new ViewDefinition(typeof(TWindow), () => new TWindow()))
}
```

Comment: really that simple? How did I miss that